# Simple Array of Images in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, image

I am a newbie and there are a lot of info about Images Array ... so much different info and circumstances that I did not made it work for me!

I have some images to "store" in to an array and then recall "from index".

As I am trying to learn ... I did the same thing working using simple text:

```
.h FILE

NS Array *arrayexample;
```

and then in the implementation file ...

```
.m FILE
arrayexample = [ [ NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"word1",@"word2",@"word3", nil];

.
.
.
.
    NSLog(@"\nIl computer ha scelto: %@", [arrayexample objectAtIndex:0]); //Here I recall and show "word1"
```

I'd like to do something like this for now (the beginnings) but with images. Storing images into array and then show recalling them from index!

Any idea please?

thanks!!!

Comment: NSArray, not NS Array

Comment: Yes, sorry. Typing mistake!

Answer (score 1):

If the images have been added to the project, then the `UIImage imageNamed` method can be used to load them into an array.

```
NSArray *example = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                    nil];
```